# get the value of the radio check button , it sent "on " instead of the real value

Tags: angular

I want to display the value of gender in radio button I got it when I do [value]
but the problem id I got "on" value when the radio button selected and sent to my API check my code 
this HTML ---

```
  <div class="form-check">
                      <input #patientGender [(ngModel)]="patient.gender" name="gender"   class="form-check-input" type="radio"  [value] = "2"  />
                      <label class="form-check-label" > 
                        Female
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check" >
                        <input #patientGender  [(ngModel)]="patient.gender"  name="gender" class="form-check-input" type="radio"   [value] = "1" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" >
                          Male
                        </label>
                      </div>
                </div>
```

check ts file

```
add(fname: string , email : string , mname : string , lname :string, DOB: Date, lastCheck:Date
     , status: number ,gender:number , Active :boolean   ): void {
       this.patientService.addPatient({ fname , email , mname , lname , DOB , 
      lastCheck , status , gender , Active} as Patient)
     .subscribe( patient => {
      this.patients.push(patient);
     });
  }
```

when it displays the data it correct it select the correct button, but I want to send data it send "on" value instead of 1 or 2, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it sends"? Is it what's received by `add`? Can you show how/where this method is called?

Comment: yes exactly  , this method called if u click the submit button                 <button (click)="add(patientName.value , patientEmail.value , patientMiddle.value , patientLast.value , patientDOB.value , patientCheck.value , patientStatus.value  , patientGender.value , patientActive.value );" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Create</button>
  when fill all needed fields it call add function then call the add function in the services,ts this the code in the html

Comment: I still don't understand how that's possible. Here's a minimal [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktckhh) with your code and a dummy patient. Check the console to see 1 or 2 displayed.

Comment: Oh, okay, you're passing the value like that... Let me answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[value]="1"` and `[value]="2"` with `value="1"` and `value="2"`.

Reason: `patientGender.value` will read the actual DOM element's `value` attribute, which is what you need with the way your code currently works.

**Better alternative**: pass data from `patient` (your model, as opposed to the HTML inputs' values) to `add`, which is a lot cleaner/Angular-ish:

`(click)="add(patient.name, patient.email, ...)"`.

I would also suggest:

- moving this code to a method in your component's script, e.g. `addPatient()`.),
- creating a `Patient` type and passing a single object of that type around, instead of every patient field individually.

Comment: thanks a lot , actually i need that way coz im using this form also to edit the data , beside creating , when user click on the exsting user i will send him to this form to update the data , when user click on create new i will send him to this form also  with empty  field thats why i put the [] around the value , and ur suggestion fix my problem i pass the data from patient model , and now work as suppose to be , sound like when i was using #patientName not send the value it send on coz the value was in []

Answer (score 1):

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x8eaxf) shows the issue.

Accessing:

```
{{ patient.gender }} <!-- html -->
this.patient.gender // controller
```

Gives the value you want.

Accessing:

```
{{ patientGender.value }} <!-- html -->
 this.patientGender.value // controller
```

Gives you 'on'